# How can I rotate two images in 3d with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement this example of 3d geometric transform with css:

[3D Geometric Transform](http://animateyourhtml5.appspot.com/pres/index.html?lang=en#9)

But my animation is not working like that example and this is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <style>
  #im1 { transform: translateZ(25px); }
  #im2 { transform: translateZ(-25px); transform: translateY(-50px); }
  #obj1 {
    animation: theRotate 2s linear infinite;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;}

  @keyframes theRotate
  {
    from {transform: rotateY(0deg)   }
    to   {transform: rotateY(360deg) }
  }
</style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" id="obj1">
        <img src="wicon2.png" id="im1" style="width:50px">
        <img src="wicon.png" id="im2" style="width:50px">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

According to [this](http://animateyourhtml5.appspot.com/pres/index.html?lang=en#10), with perspective:1000 the animation should work fine, but it doesn't.

If there is another simple way to do this, maybe with JS, will be fine too.

I appreciate your time, thanks.

Comment: it works, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGJjYp , wich browser did you use to test ?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: As you can see, your test is not working too, not like this http://animateyourhtml5.appspot.com/pres/index.html?lang=en#9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the initial link/example you posted and copied the relevant CSS code from there and adapted it to your existing code. The following edit of your posted code should work in the intended way (shown in the linked example).

please note: If you run the snippet below, it will rotate empty images, because the image link is still the same from your post (`wicon1.png`)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<style>

.scene3d
{
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.object3d
{
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  /*top: 20px;*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face3d
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 165px;
  top: 15px;
}

#im1 { transform: translateZ(150px); }
#im2 { transform: translateZ(-150px); }
.scene3d.begin { perspective: 100000px; }
.scene3d.end   { perspective: 1000px; }
#obj1 { animation: theRotate 4s linear infinite; }

@keyframes theRotate
{
  from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  to   {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}



</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row scene3d">

    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 object3d" id="obj1">
      <img src="wicon1.png" id="im1" class="face3d" style="width:50px">
      <img src="wicon2.png" id="im2" class="face3d" style="width:50px">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it works but if you change the width of the images to 50px, you will see the effect is lost and i dont know why, is something like the rotation have no a central axis.

Comment: I see, am not sure why it is behaving quite differently when just dividing all values by 10. As a hack you could add `transform: scale(0.1);` to `.scene3d` with `img`'s `width` set to `500px` to make the whole scene smaller but keeping the original effect intact.